# How can I get country specific data from netCDF4 file containing global data

Tags: python, arcgis, netcdf, qgis, netcdf4

I have downloaded tasmax dataset from ESGF website. The .nc files in the dataset contain global data from years 1850 to 2014. However, I want data for specific countries like Bangladesh, Sri Lanka, Pakistan, Maldives, etc. from that global data and then work on those specific countries.

Deatils of one .nc file which contains data from 1850 to 1899:

```
table_id: day
table_info: Creation Date:(20 February 2019) MD5:951084b632bd52c3f6224e495b1cb65e
title: INM-CM4-8 output prepared for CMIP6
tracking_id: hdl:21.14100/819efd11-8094-46b4-86a9-1296bfe83b55
variable_id: tasmax

dict_keys(['time', 'time_bnds', 'lat', 'lat_bnds', 'lon', 'lon_bnds', 'height', 'tasmax']) 

dimensions(sizes): time(5475), lat(120), lon(180), bnds(2)
```

Details of tasmax variable:

```
    tasmax=ds.variables['tasmax']
    print(tasmax)
```

This gives output:

```
   <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
   float32 tasmax(time, lat, lon)
        standard_name: air_temperature
        long_name: Daily Maximum Near-Surface Air Temperature
        comment: maximum near-surface (usually, 2 meter) air 
    temperature (add cell_method attribute 'time: max')
        units: K
        original_name: tasmax
        cell_methods: area: mean time: maximum (interval: 1 day)
        cell_measures: area: areacella
        history: 2019-05-28T11:29:24Z altered by CMOR: Treated 
    scalar dimension: 'height'.
        coordinates: height
        missing_value: 1e+20
        _FillValue: 1e+20
    unlimited dimensions: time
    current shape = (5475, 120, 180)
    filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used


    tasmax.dimentions
    ('time', 'lat', 'lon')
```

This file when plotted shows tasmax data perday for entire globe. I need only a perticular country data instead of the globe.
I am using python but I can also use QGIS and ArcGIS if that is a better way.

I tried putting specific coordinates in the lat and lon spaces like this:

```
   print(temp[:,23.35,90])
```

Where 23.35 and 90 are lat and lon for some point in Bangladesh.

This gives output: [282.4348  281.53607 283.49426 ... 280.90012 282.33377 282.48367]

In this way I can extract data for specific points. But country has many lat lon points so I cannot do this for each point as that would not be efficient.

I also created a numpy dataframe and used it to extract the data into csv file.

I wish to do trend analysis to see the tasmax variance over bangladesh. For that, I need to have the time series data for bangladesh. I need to detect the change in temprature over bangladesh over the years.

I wish to do 1. Mann Kendall Test, 2. Spearman Rank Correlation test, 3. Sen's slope, 4. Variance Coorelation approch with M K Test.

So, I need the gridded dataset to be of only bangladesh instead of the entire globe.

I tried importing the data into qgis with a world shapefile. The netCDF4 data does not overlap with the shapefile. In fact, it is flipped as well. [image: qgis image]

I don't know how to flip it the right side and how to make it overlap correctly.

Also I have realised that the resolution of my netCDF4 data is 100kms which is very large. How do I reduce it to 25kms?

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76184467/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: +1 to the above. You will need to tell us how you want to convert gridded Netcdf data to country level data. There are various scientific methodologies for doing this. Tell us how you want to do it and we can help

Answer (score 2):

You can use QGIS to obtain data you want. You should add vector layers of your countries and add netcdf file as raster layer. For your contries shapefiles, you can easily find global country shapefiles online, then open attribute table, toggle editting mode and delete all countries except yours. Note that you should do it seperatly for every country you want. Then from menu:

•   Raster>extraction>clip raster by mask layer

[clip raster by layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUC1a.png)

Select your gridded raster data and your country shapefile as polygon, save it as netcdf file. Now you have a gridded time series data only have your country. Also by data tools in qgis, you can also take average of all points inside your country boundaries.

Comment: For the "data tools in qgis" mentioned in this answer, try Processing toolbox -> Raster analysis -> Zonal statistics